# PHP and Java socket communication. socket_read() hangs

Tags: java, php, sockets

me and a friend have been fiddling with PHP sockets for the past couple of days trying to get it to communicate with Java server socket. We have tried multiple different methods/solutions and have looked through quite a handful of similar issues/solutions to no avail.

For the code I currently have (since I cant remember all the changes I made or tried), socket_send() works and the java server receives the message. But interestingly enough, if the socket_read() is in the PHP file the last print to the java console is "Client response: ..." but if socket_read() is commented out it goes through the entire java program.

I am not really sure why this happens but I'm guessing this is the reason data is not being read into the PHP script. I know that it reaches the socket_read() code because if I force close the server I get "Warning: socket_read(): unable to read from socket [10054]: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

**PHP File**

```
<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$port = 1000;

echo "Creating Socket...<br>";
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket");

echo "Connecting to host...<br>";
$connection = socket_connect($socket,$host,$port) or die("Could not connect to host");

$message ="Message to send".PHP_EOL;
socket_send($socket,$message,strlen($message),0);

sleep(10);
echo "Done sleep";
while (($buffer = socket_read($socket, 1024))!=false) {
    echo("Data sent was:" . $buffer . "<br>");
}

socket_close($socket);
?>
```

**Java File**

```
try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1000);

    Socket currentClient = null;
    while(currentClient == null) {
        try {
            // accepts incoming socket connection
            currentClient = serverSocket.accept();
            if(currentClient!=null) {
                System.out.println("Client Connected: " + currentClient);

                //create streams for socket
                OutputStream out = currentClient.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(currentClient.getInputStream()));

                String line = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client response: " + line);
                }

                System.out.println("Writing to os");
                os.println("Hello world\r\n");

                System.out.println("flushing OS");
                os.flush();

                System.out.println("Done");

                os.close();
                out.close();
                br.close();
                currentClient.close();
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            currentClient.close();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    serverSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT**
i removed the while loop in the Java file and it now works which is weird but ill take it as a temporary fix. obviously if multiple lines are sent then only the first line would be read. Still not sure why it works if socket_read is not present.

Comment: FWIW, `ServerSocket.accept()` will never return `null`.

Comment: @SeanBright Interesting, did not know that. Thanks for the input.